# Entity doesnt appear at /api

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a work project with Symfony 6 and we use Api platform.

I need to make my entity to an api resource with only an endpoint for get the list of all my entity in db.

My problem is i dont understand for what my entity doesnt appear as api resource at the 127.0.0.1/api and the endpoint dont work too. I try to create a new test entity with the symfony maker for make it directly as entity resource but it dont work too i dont understand what is the problem.

My entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use App\Repository\BoxTypeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BoxTypeRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class BoxType
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    private ?string $manufacturer = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'boxTypeId', targetEntity: Box::class)]
    private Collection $boxes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->boxes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

My composer.json :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^4.6",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.21",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.15",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/asset": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.16",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.0.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.2",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.0.*"
    }
}
```

I try to make a new entity with the maker and make it directly as an api resource but its not work

I try to upgrade Api platform and there is some conflict with my composer that i dont understand

Comment: Is the api documentation page displayed in swagger? At least without resources

Answer (score 2):

In your file `config/api_platform.yaml` check that your mapping is correct, the mapping key should look like this:

```yaml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

You can also completely remove the mapping key and api platform will expose your API's automatically as long as you have the attribute `#[ApiResource]` on your class.

See this [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/getting-started/#mapping-the-entities) for reference